# ternary relationship with @ElementCollection - left join fetch misbehaving

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, bidirectional-relation

JPA 2, Eclipselink 2.3.2

I'm trying to model a ternary relationship with two `@ElementCollection` as opposed to two `@OneToMany`'s mainly so I can make the junction object an `@Embeddable` instead of an @Entity and avoid needing an `@Id` for the nested object.

For example

```
@Entity
public class Project {
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="assignment", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"))
   public Set<Assignment> assignments;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="assignment", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"))
   public Set<Assignment> assignments;
}

@Embeddable
public class Assignment {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
  public Employee employee;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="project_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  public Project project;
}
```

To persist, I am adding `Assignment` instances to `Project` instances, with reference to the right `Employee`.  This works fine.

Further, I can reference the list of `Project`s through the `Employee` just fine as well.

*However*, if I load employees with a query with `left join fetch`, like `select e from Employee e left join fetch e.assignments`,  the associated Assignment/Project objects don't get loaded *even though* I can see the DB query is in fact doing the join and the data is coming back.

What is it about the above mappings that somehow doesn't interact with `left join fetch` properly?

I have used `left join fetch` in simpler `@ElementCollection` mappings with no problem so I'm wondering what the problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: Also confirmed it's not a cache issue - flushing whole JPA cache has no impact